# Creating Thread from ListenerAdapter stops it from listening for events Java JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

Hi I have this JDA Discord Bot I am working on and I am struggling with Threads a bit. My main bot class extends ListenerAdapter and I want it to listen for a command that then starts a scheduled service to post a message once a week. The problem is when the Thread is created it starts performing that but the main class stops listening.

Wondering whether I should make an inner class that is the ListenerAdapter and have them both in threads perhaps, or whether there is another solution I am missing. I have done some work with Threads at uni but not much experience.

```
public class Main extends ListenerAdapter {
static Thread SER;

public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
... 
}
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event){
if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!startmessages")){
        try {
            SER = new Thread(new ScheduledExecutorRepeat(event.getChannel(),event.getGuild()));
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            executor.submit(SER);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Creating messages");
    }
}
class ScheduledExecutorRepeat implements Runnable {

private int count = 0;
MessageChannel channel;
Guild guild;
ScheduledExecutorService ses;
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

public ScheduledExecutorRepeat(MessageChannel mc,Guild g) throws InterruptedException {

    channel = mc;
    guild = g;

    ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    run();



}
public void run(){

    Runnable task1 = () -> {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Running...Weekly Message - count : " + count);

    };

    // init Delay = 5, repeat the task every 1 second
    scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 5, 1000*60*60*24*7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("count :" + count);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program was stuck in the loop at the end of the ScheduledExecutorRepeat class. Removing the while loop fixed the issue. The scheduled messages work and the bot is still listening for messages.